# How can I suspend my Ubuntu 20.04 system?

Tags: suspend

I have two disks in my PC: one with Windows 7 installed in it and the second one has Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

After I installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, my computer cannot be in suspended status and the fan is in operation always. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the solution... I added the "suspend button" at power off/logout buttons and my PC now can enter suspend state. But at first, after clicking to wake it up my monitor was remaining black.

My graphisc card is Nvidia Geforce 450 ts, so I installed the 390 driver and now everything is okay and with maximum resolution also...
Hope that helps...